# Increase ASP.NET page timeout

Tags: asp.net, session, timeout

I have a long running method which can take a minute. On my local, it's OK, but on the server, I get a 504 response. I assume this means the page is timing out. Is it SessionState that I need to change in the web.config? I tried that but didn't help.

What's the property to increase page timeout?

Thank you.

Comment: Dude, you need to learn how to use google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should solve your problem. 
In the web.config put

```
<location path="somefile.aspx">
    <system.web>
            <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180"/>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Here is the [source](http://forums.asp.net/t/1040377.aspx/1)

Comment: note that it does have effect in Debug configuration. Only in Release. So if you are debugging then this attribute is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the HttpRuntime settings.  I believe in your case you would tweak the `executionTimeout` property (which by default I believe is 90 seconds).

Here's a full rundown on the HttpRuntime settings: [HttpRuntime Element (ASP.Net Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/e1f13641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4000"
    enable = "True"
    requestLengthDiskThreshold="512"
    useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="True"
    executionTimeout="90"
    versionHeader="1.1.4128"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it has nothing to do with Session. It has to do with the Request Timeout. One thing that might work is to have this on your Web.config:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" /> <!-value is in secs-->
```